# Create Vertical Owl slider with 2 itmes at a time

Tags: vertical-alignment, owl-carousel, vertical-scrolling

I am using `Owl` carousel to create slider I created one horizontal slider but I need one `vertical` one as well with three items at a time.

[image: vertical_slider]

I searched but no answer or related post found.

Update:

I used slick slider that time and that was working as i want. But in owl, I am not able to do that.

Comment: I ended up using slick slider https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick,  set vertical slider to true,

Answer (score 0):

In css you should add:

```
      .item {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
      .owl-carousel{
             transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
```

In js add :

```
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ 
           loop: true,
           items: 3,
           animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
           animateIn: 'slideInUp'
         });
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a CodePen that has vertical owl slider:

https://codepen.io/thirdender/pen/aOYyGb

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  items: 1,
  nav: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
  animateIn: 'slideInUp'
});
```

Comment: i need 3 data at a time Sir.